# My first perl script is generating an error

Tags: perl

my perl script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict ;
use warnings;
print "Hello $name \n"
```

I get this error:

> Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name at fst_pscpt.pl.

This is really stopping my progress.do we need to include any packages???

Thanks & Regards,
B.Raviteja

Comment: There is no need to use the `-w` flag when you have `use warnings;` in  your code.  `use warnings;` is considered to be the correct, modern usage.  For more info on this you can read perllexwarn.  At this stage in your Perl learning it may not make much sense, but you deserve a link in case you don't want to blindly absorb my assertions as fact.  http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html

Comment: Good part of your example is that you have started following Perl  best practices from your first script

Answer (score 13):

You haven't declared any variable `$name`. So you'll need to get that variable somehow. For example, if you wanted to get it from the command line, you could do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
my $name = $ARGV[0];
print "Hello, $name!\n";
```

And then call your program like so:

```
./myprog.pl Rafe
```

And get the output:

```
Hello, Rafe!
```

Also, you don't have a semicolon at the end of the last line. You'll need that as well.

Comment: `s/ARGV[1]/ARGV[0]/`. And the semicolon is optional at the end of a block, including the end of the code. Perl is very forgiving in that way and in many other ways.

Comment: @socket good habit to be in to always end a statement with a semicolon, though.

Comment: I agree and almost always use optional semicolons. However *you'll need that* is a bit too strong for the truth if it's optional.

Comment: Agreed. Semicolons in Perl are statement separators, not statement terminators. Having one at the end of your block/program is a good habit, but you don't _need_ it.

Answer (score 4):

[diagnostics](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html) gives you more useful help in this case:

```
$ perl -Mdiagnostics fst_pscpt.pl
Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name at fst_pscpt.pl line 4.
Execution of fst_pscpt.pl aborted due to compilation errors (#1)
    (F) You've said "use strict" or "use strict vars", which indicates
    that all variables must either be lexically scoped (using "my"),
    declared beforehand using "our", or explicitly qualified to say
    which package the global variable is in (using "::").

Uncaught exception from user code:
        Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name at fst_pscpt.pl line 4.
Execution of fst_pscpt.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
 at fst_pscpt.pl line 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `$name` when you `use strict;` (which includes strict vars). Just insert the line:

```
my $name;
```

before using it.

Comment: Well, you'll also want to set it to something other than `undef`, or the `print` won't work very well.

Comment: The print will work fine. You'll get a waring about not initializing $name, though...